# Getting records from a table based on a filter field and Between but also having the OR logic for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a this table, where I store multiple ids and an age range (def1,def2)

```
CREATE TABLE "template_requirements" (
  "_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "templateid" INTEGER,
  "def1" VARCHAR(255),
  "def2" VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY("_id")
)
```

Having values such as:

```
templateid | def1 | def2
-------------------------------
100        | 7    | 25
200        | 40   | 90
300        | 7    | 25
300        | 40   | 60
```

As you see for templateid `300`, we have an or logic: age between 7 and 25 or age between 40 and 60.

I want to get all the template ids that are **not** for a certain `age` like 25...
What's the problem?

If I run a query like this one:

```
SELECT group_concat(templateid) 
 FROM template_requirements 
where 1=1 and '25' not between cast(def1 as integer) 
                       and cast(def2 as integer)
```

it returns 200, 300, which is wrong, as the 300 matched on row 40 to 60, but shouldn't be included in the result as we have a condition with same templateid 7 to 25 that fails the not beetween stuff.

How would be the correct query in SQLite, I would like to keep the group_concat stuff.

Comment: You have a syntax error; the `and` before the `'25'`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I have some other stuff there too, I posted a reduced table schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try `EXCEPT`:

```
sqlite> select group_concat(templateid)
          from (select templateid from template_requirements
                except
                select templateid from template_requirements
                 where 25 between cast(def1 as integer) and cast(def2 as integer));
```

... show me those `"templateid"`s except those which have an age range encompassing 25.

Or how about a similar `WHERE NOT IN`:

```
sqlite> select group_concat(distinct templateid)
          from template_requirements
         where templateid not in
                 (select templateid from template_requirements
                   where 25 between cast(def1 as integer) and cast(def2 as integer));
```

Both are fairly "colloquially accurate" SQL representations of what you're trying to do...

Comment: Update your first proposition to have group_concat and I will accept it.

Comment: Please review the query again, is not that simple, that group_concat won't work in that place as it will concat all fields together and will treat the joined string against the except.

Answer (score 1):

I think i'ts not sqlite but the query, try this:

```
SELECT templateid
FROM template_requirements 

/*You want this values*/
WHERE '25' not between cast(def1 as integer) and cast(def2 as integer)

/*You don't want results with this values (with this you should eliminate 300)*/
AND templateid NOT IN (
  SELECT templateid
  FROM template_requirements 
  WHERE '25' between cast(def1 as integer) and cast(def2 as integer)
  )
```